# Need to insert a dash(-) into a sql row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, character

I'm working with SQL SERVER and I would like to insert(Not select), a row with values like 123456-7, so they get stored like that in the database, however I've tried every single type for the column and they won't allow me to do that.

It just won't execute the query or swap the value for NULL in case I set it to accept nulls.

Actual Database Settings

[image]

Correct Insert

```
Insert into Personal_Cost
Values ('2018-01-01', 'a', '79745060', 1000)
```

Error Insert

```
Insert into Personal_Cost
Values ('2018-01-01', 'a', '79745060-1', 1000)
```

Comment: Add examples of queries you've tried so that we'll have something we can comment about.

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide us with some more information? Some sample data and an example of what you hope your solution to look like would be helpful.

Comment: Just edited the post

Comment: Are you receiving any error when executing the insert statement ? Can you add `N` in front of the '79745060-1' as N'79745060-1' and try

Comment: When I set 'NOT NULL', I get error, when it's disabled, it replaces the value for NULL

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: When you set `NOT NULL` to the field, you _need to update_ some value for the existing rows.

Comment: I'm deleting the whole table dat before I insert, so It shouldn't be a problem

Comment: It's a massive insertion by the way, so it's not just one column value reporting that error, but at least six

Comment: I suspect the problem would go away if you used a column list in your `INSERT`.  Without a script that reproduces the issue, I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar certainly allows the data that you want to be stored...

```
create table #table
(lname varchar(150))

insert into #table
(lname)
values
('123456-7-8')

select * from #table
```

Comment: It should, but it just replaces it for null

Comment: can you post the create table script, including whatever constraints are on that table?

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually replace every defective dash(-) character for a space since it didn't allowed me to insert underscore(_) neither.

I don't know what's wrong, if it's Microsoft Tool or a not-allowed character mistaken for dash character(which i doubt since i replaced it on my own), but it didn't worked the way I wanted.

I hope your answers work for someone else who may have a similar problem.

Comment: I created same environment as yours . Can you share what are you getting error message ?
[Image 1](https://i.hizliresim.com/Y68DZZ.png) , 
[Image 2](https://i.hizliresim.com/8zWMR7.png)

Comment: Your images are blocked my college internet provider